# Get the text in a Textblock or Textbox in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

i am currently having troubles in adding an item to a list using mvvm, i have successfully able to add items in a list using this simple method:

```
    private DelegateCommand _addItemCommand;
            public ICommand AddItemCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_addItemCommand == null)
                    {
                        _addItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddItem);
                    }
                    return _addItemCommand;
                }
            }

    void AddItem()
            {

           DessertData.Add(new CakeDataSample {Samplename="Black Forest" ,ImagePath="Assets/Black-Forest.jpg"});
            }
```

now what im trying to achieve is to get that text of the Textblock or textbox and add them to the list. i want to do it like this:

```
DessertData.Add(new CakeDataSample {Samplename=txtCakename.text ,ImagePath=myImageSource}); //or something likethat
```

how am i going to get that text? is there something that im going add?

Comment: Have a `string` property in your VM and Bind that to the Textblock or TextBox in twoway.. use that property while adding..

Comment: like how? im sorry if asking stupid questions im still learning the basics of mvvm can you please give me a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below code,

```
private string text;
public string Text
{
     get
     {
          return text;
     }
     set
     {
          text = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Text");
     }
}
```

Use this in your VM... i trust you have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCakename" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

This will bind the text to txtCakename to Text Property..

and in you AddItem method,

```
DessertData.Add(new CakeDataSample {Samplename=this.Text,ImagePath=myImageSource});
```

Comment: thank you! it helps me a lot!!! and oh a small question, is it also applicable that i implement `ViewModel` instead of `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: ummm this code is correct but im having troubles with setting the initial text. whenever a page is navigated (like form load in WinForms), i set different text in a textblock,and then there must be an initial text before i get that text and add them to list,but then i see blank textblock. how do i resolve this?